# Singleton Implementation: counter not incrementing as expected with multiple pointers to instance

Tags: class, c++11, object, singleton, instance

The following program aims to instantiate and use the singleton pattern class proposed by Loki Astari and accepted as answer at the following link.
[C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289)

Note the addition of a simple counter, by way of the private `counter` variable, along with the `increment()` mutator, and `getCtr()` accessor methods.

Expected program output is:

```
0
1
Press any key to exit...
```

The actual output is

```
0
0
Press any key to exit...
```

Why is the counter in the singleton class not being incremented as expected?

What follows is a minimal, complete, and verifiable program, written to illustrate the issue.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class S {
public:
    static S & getInstance() {
        static S instance;
        instance.counter = 0; // initialize counter to 0
        return instance;
    }
    S(S const &) = delete;
    void operator = (S const &) = delete;

    void increment() { ++counter; }
    int getCtr() { return counter; }
private:
    S() {}
    int counter;
};

int main() {
    S * s; // s is a pointer to the singleton object
    S * t; // t is another pointer to the singleton object.

    std::cout << s->getInstance().getCtr() << std::endl;
    s->getInstance().increment(); // increment counter
    std::cout << t->getInstance().getCtr() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press any key to exit...";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Thx, Keith :^)

Comment: Because your getInstance() sets the value to zero every time you call it?

Comment: How do I properly initialize this value to 0?

Comment: You initialize it in the constructor as any other values that need to be initialized when the object is created.

Comment: Is it necessary to invoke the ``getInstance()`` method every time that I need access to the object, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2):

your problem is you are initializing the counter inside the

> getInstance() method

instead, initialize it inside the constructor
your code should be like the following,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class S {
public:
    static S & getInstance() {
        static S instance;
       // instance.counter = 0; // initialize counter to 0
        return instance;
    }
    S(S const &) = delete;
    void operator = (S const &) = delete;

    void increment() { ++counter; }
    int getCtr() { return counter; }
private:
    S() {counter =0;}
    int counter;
};

int main() {
    S * s; // s is a pointer to the singleton object
    S * t; // t is another pointer to the singleton object.

    std::cout << s->getInstance().getCtr() << std::endl;
    s->getInstance().increment(); // increment counter
    std::cout << t->getInstance().getCtr() << std::endl;
    
    
    s->getInstance().increment(); // increment counter
    std::cout << t->getInstance().getCtr() << std::endl;
    
    s->getInstance().increment(); // increment counter
    std::cout << t->getInstance().getCtr() << std::endl;
    
     s->getInstance().increment(); // increment counter
    std::cout << t->getInstance().getCtr() << std::endl;
    
     s->getInstance().increment(); // increment counter
    std::cout << t->getInstance().getCtr() << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Press any key to exit...";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

then the **Output** will be

```
0                                                                                                                                             
1                                                                                                                                             
2                                                                                                                                             
3                                                                                                                                             
4                                                                                                                                             
5                                                                                                                                             
Press any key to exit...
```